# Passport expiry and holding a valid visa

Tags: visas, passports

I have a contract work permit letter from Daimler, which is valid until May 10, 2018.

I have a valid visa up to May 15, 2018 and I am planning to travel to Germany from April 1, 2018 to May 13, 2018 with the same visa.

But my existing passport is expiring on May 13, 2018. Will it be fine travelling with this passport?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be fine!

Your passport must be valid at least three months beyond your departure date. In your case - at least until August 13, 2018.

[Source 1](https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/europe/germany/passport-visa/), [source 2](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/passport-requirements.html).